# Is there any way to publish the Solution in VS 2019?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

To make it simple,

let say I have a solution with 3 projects (1, 2 and 3)

```
Solution
    Project-1    (Console Application referencing Project-2 and Project-3)
    Project-2    (Class Library)
    Project-3    (Class Library)
```

When I build/rebuild the Solution, all looks good, meaning let say I update some code in Project-2/3, the Console Application (Project-1) can get those update.

The issue I encounter is not the build but when I am doing the publish.

Let say I publish Project-1, 2 and 3 already initially. All are good.

Then, I change the code in Project-2 and then rebuild **the whole Solution** (by right-click at the Solution -> Rebuild Solution)

Then, at this time, when I publish Project-1, it is still using old code in Project-2.

I can resolve it by re-publishing the Project-2 then Project-1, but it is tedious when there are many Projects under 1 Solution and quite a few people are working at the same Solution.

Unlike Build/Rebuild, it can be done in Solution level. Publish can only be done in Project level 1 by 1.

Is there any way I can publish the Solution (which can trigger publishing all the projects in the solution)?

Comment: Are you using project references in Project-1 to reference projects 2 and 3? I'm guessing Project-1 is using the published products and not Project References. Also if this is one solution, why are you publishing projects 2 and 3? Can you let Project-1 pull in the project references and then just publish Project-1?

Comment: We cannot publish in the Solution level. You can add ProjectReference to Project1 like the second method in my answer and publish project1 when other references are changed.

Comment: @JonathanDodds Are you using project references in Project-1 to reference projects 2 and 3? (Yes, I use "Add Project Reference ..." in IDE GUI). Also if this is one solution, why are you publishing projects 2 and 3? (Because when I published Project-1, it complained one of the dll cannot be found. I have no idea why, so I published all the project finally, but results in the problem in this question). Can you let Project-1 pull in the project references and then just publish Project-1? (It is already a project reference in Project-1 to Project-2 and Project-3)

Comment: What DLL could not be found? The class library DLL (e.g. project2.dll) or a DLL that the class library DLL depends on?

Answer (score -1):

Check your .csproj file how can you add references?

***1.Publish Class Library and reference the .dll file like this:***

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="ClassLibrary1">
    <HintPath>..\ClassLibrary1\bin\Release\net6.0\ClassLibrary1.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

***2.Add Project Reference from the solution like this***

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If you use the first method to add reference, after you modify the code of project2, you need to republish project2 to apply the changes to project1.

If you use the second method the changes to project2 will be applied to project1 instantly, you just need to republish project1.

I made a simple test like this:
[image]

Comment: I am already using "Add Project Reference ..." in IDE GUI, also checked the csproj file, they are all <ProjectReference>

Comment: @kzfid I added a simple test process, is this the effect you want？

Comment: Thanks for  you testing. Yes, that is exactly what I want. I just tried a simple solution as yours, it is working as expected (same result with you). I guess there may be other factors (published as self-contained single file, linux exe instead of windows, under a git repo, etc.), which result in my case. But I get your point that normally speaking, when publishing an app, it will automatically pick up the change (recompile if any change) in other projects within the same solution (provided that they are project references).

Comment: Is it possible to provide more code to help us reproduce this issue? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).